# Find a vector of strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of strings like:

```
vector=c("a","hb","cd")
```

and also I have a matrix which has a column, each element of this column is a list of strings which separated by `"|"` separator, like:

1 `"ab|hb"`

2 `"ab|hbc|cd"`

I want to find each string of vector appears in which row of matrix completely.

For the above vector, the result is:

```
NA, 1, 2
```

Comment: Is there one match at maximum?

Comment: Yes, a complete match is one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strsplit` for splitting strings:

```
x <- strsplit("ab|hbc|cd", split="|", fixed=T)
```

and then check if values of `vector` appear in the data, e.g.

```
sapply(vector, function(x) x %in% strsplit("a|ab|cd|efg|bh",
                                     split="|", fixed=T)[[1]])
```

Warning: `strsplit` outputs data as a list, so in the example above I extract only the first element of the list with `[[1]]`, however you can deal with it in other way if you choose.

EDIT: answering to your question on data as a vector:

```
data <- c("ab|cd|ef", "aaa|b", "ab", "wf", "fg|hb|a", "cd|cd|df")

sapply(sapply(data, function(x) strsplit(x, split="|", fixed=T)[[1]]),
  function(y) sapply(vector, function(z) z %in% y))
```

Comment: My data is a vector, and each element of this vector is a combined string which separated by "|" delimiter. I want to find elements of first vector in the second vector.

Comment: so you can use nested `sapply`: `sapply(vector, function (x) sapply(x, function (y) ...)` where `...` is a body of your function. That enables you to iterate through all the values from the data vector and through all the values in `vector` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using regular expressions:

```
# Example data
vector <- c("a","hb","cd")
mat <- matrix(c("ab|hb", "ab|hbc|cd"), nrow = 2)

sapply(paste0("\\b", vector, "\\b"), function(x)
         if(length(tmp <- grep(x, mat[ , 1]))) tmp else NA,
       USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] NA  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks, It solves my problem, but I didn't understand how it is done? Could you give me some details about why you add \\b to the first and the last of vector elements?

Comment: @Zaynab This is done to create a regex pattern. The `\\b` indicates a word boundary. The beginning and the end of the string and the `|` are word boundaries.